# Jackson Json, marshalling ByteBuffer

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there any restriction on the minimum size of the data that should be present in ByteBuffer so that Jackson will be able to serialize it ? I get BufferUnderflowException while doing so.
But it works fine when the size of data present is large.

```
public class MyTest {
    private static class Wrapper {
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
        }
        public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void fails() throws Exception {
        // Fails
        ByteBuffer smallBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("small".getBytes());
        Wrapper wrapper1 = new Wrapper();
        wrapper1.setBuffer(smallBuffer);
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(wrapper1));
    }

    @Test
    public void works() throws Exception {
        // Works
        ByteBuffer smallBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("larger string works, wonder why".getBytes());
        Wrapper wrapper1 = new Wrapper();
        wrapper1.setBuffer(smallBuffer);
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(wrapper1));
    }

}
```

Exception stack trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.nio.BufferUnderflowException) (through reference chain: com.test.Wrapper["buffer"]->java.nio.HeapByteBuffer["int"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jackson will normally run into problems when serializing complex objects with lots of internal state and/or non-standard getter/setter methods. In general, you should always stick to pure POJOs in the object hierarchy to be serialized.

In this particular case, you've created a wrapper that contains a ByteBuffer. Well, Jackson actually tries to serialize the *entire* byte buffer object (not just its byte contents), and if you look under the covers its actually trying to write out all these 'properties':

```
[
    property 'short' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getShort), 
    property 'char' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getChar),
    property 'int' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getInt),
    property 'long' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getLong),
    property 'float' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getFloat),
    property 'double' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#getDouble),
    property 'direct' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#isDirect),
    property 'readOnly' (via method java.nio.HeapByteBuffer#isReadOnly)
]
```

Its just by dumb luck that the second case works (because the buffer is long enough to get all the above shown methods invoked on it without underflowing). If you want to serialize the buffer as bytes, then either:

- change the wrapper property to `byte[]`
- keep the property as `ByteBuffer`, but mark it as `@JsonIgnore`able and provide an alternate accessor method around it that converts to a `byte[]`

Example of first:

```
class Wrapper {
    final byte[] buffer;

    public Wrapper(final ByteBuffer buffer) {
        super();
        this.buffer = buffer != null ? buffer.array() : new byte[0];
    }
}
```